# UICollectionViewCell change background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionview` with sections and two cell class.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

myCell *cell;

    firstDayInMonth = [self dayWeekStart:[self getDateFromItem:dateFromStart section:indexPath.section row:1]];

    if (indexPath.row < firstDayInMonth) {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellCalendarEmpty" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellCalendar" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

I have start item, section and period. Beginning from the start section and item i need to change background color cell depending on period. i need to change only `cellCalendar`. I use `cellCalendarEmpty` to move first `cellCalendar`.

Answer (score 0):

Fix by handling both branches of the case (all cases) when you configure, e.g.:

```
if (indexPath.section == todayMonthSection && indexPath.item == dayPlusShift){

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0/255.0 green:162.0/255.0 blue:161.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  // whatever the default color is
}
```

If you're using a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell, you may also reset to defaults by implementing the prepareForReuse method.